# In Visual Studio (2008), can I start up a website debug session as the web root?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, cassini

I have a website in my solution, let's assume it is in a folder called /Solution/Website1.
When I debug it in Visual Studio, it will come up as http://localhost:someport/Website1.
I want it to start as http://localhost:someport. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on the Website1 Project then go to the Properties Window(F4) you should see a property here for `Virtual path` try setting that to "/"

[image: Website Properties]
<sub>(source: [bendewey.com](http://www.bendewey.com/code/stackoverflow/WebSiteProperties.png))</sub>

Comment: Sorry, no such property. This is a not a web application project. It is a website project.

Comment: Correct this is for a Website Project.  I added a screenshot

Comment: Thanks, learned something - the difference between Property Pages (Shift-F4) and Properties (F4).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio 2008:

R-Click on the project heading in the Solution Explorer. Click Properties. Go to the Web tab, there will be a Servers section which will alow you to specify the port.

Comment: This is a website, not a web project.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.